# Unit testing. Reducer does not change state after dispatching action

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, ngrx-reducers

I am trying to perform simple reducer test. new StartLoading(); is dispatched this should set isLoading to true. Unfortunately it shows: 
**Expected $.isLoading = false to equal true.**

Nothing fancy. This is how test looks like:

```
   it('should set isLoading to true', () => {
        const isLoading = true;

        const action = new StartLoading();
        const newState = uiReducers(initialState, action);

        const expectedState = { ...initialState, isLoading };

        expect(newState).toEqual(expectedState);
    })
```

And reducer:

```
export interface UIState {
    isLoading: boolean;
}

export const initialState: UIState = {
    isLoading: false
};

export function uiReducers(state = initialState, action: UIActions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UIActionTypes.START_LOADING: {
            console.log('stt')
            return {
                isLoading: true,
                ...state
            };
        }
        case UIActionTypes.STOP_LOADING: {
            return {
                isLoading: false,
                ...state
            };
        }
        default:
            return {
                ...state
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you’re facing is due to the order of the elements on the `object spread operator`.

Your `initialState` has `isLoading = false` and you are setting it in the right side of the object assignment (by putting `...state` as the second part of the operator). Meaning, it will always override the `isLoading` that you are trying to set. You should try something like

```
case UIActionTypes.START_LOADING: {
            console.log('stt')
            return {
                ...state
                isLoading: true,
            };
        }
```

This way you are telling the operator to use the `state` as the origin object and to change the `isLoading` property with the new value.

If you check this [example](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers) in the documentation you will see that the state is defined in the left side and then the new properties on the right side (or in the bottom in case they are in multiple lines)

Comment: That is true. Thank you Hugo Noro.

Comment: No problem. Always glad to help :)